# How to keep version of project

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

There is Visual Studio 2008 project in TFS.

How can I get this project for my Visual Studio 2012, so that when I check in the server project is not converted.

Comment: The TFS doesn't care if it is a VS2008 or VS2012 solution, it is just the repository. The problem is VS2012 which converts the project to work with it. If you have a team, everyone should work with the same VS version.

Comment: Yeah but one part of team mast work on Visual Sutdio 2008 tow part in 2012, how can I avoid conflicts?

Comment: You could prohibit users of VS2012 to checkin .sln, .csproj or .vbproj files to TFS. You could do this by security settings (user specific, hard to administrate) or creating a checkinpolicy (same name, but two versions, so the VS2008 version does nothing, while VS2012 checks if the prohibited types are inside the changeset).

Answer (score 0):

you want one project file - vcxproj

migrate everyone to 2012
create new compile configuration
change property Platform Toolset to v90 in order to support vs 2008

keep vcproj and vcxproj

the cost of maintaining both is higher
example: team A with VS2008 adds a new file, must change also team B xproj

Answer (score 0):

Roundtripping is supported between VS2010 and VS2012 but not with VS2008. So if your 2008 users can move to 2010 that would be ideal - using VS2010 express maybe? if the featureset is sufficient.

If you cannot do that then you should consider the approach suggested by @Florea but it will be a pain to maintain since code that compiles with one platformtoolset may fail on the other and vice versa.